# How to send hardware level keyboard input by program?

Tags: winapi, keyboard-events

I have been using [keybd_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) for keyboard input by command line. However, want something that can send hardware level input, just like real keyboard.

Is there anything that suits my purpose?

I am using Windows as operating system.

Comment: c or c++? they are two different languages

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 hmm.. my coding style is maybe close to C but i dont mind C++

Comment: Edit your question so that others could get your issue

Comment: @Athira i have never been here before. Do you mean I should add tag more?

Comment: Use exact tag and try to add what you have tried and where you got stuck

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 please tell me how sending a keyboard input with winapi (may not use winapi directly, but question is asked for windows still) depends whether language is C or C++ ? Which tag OP should use if answer in both languages are acceptable?

Comment: @unlut you are asking what is the difference between C and C++? Of course it is possible to write code that is valid c and valid c++, but often the result is neither nice c nor nice c++. Asking for both limits the users that can give good answers to those who are proficient in both languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once used SendInput to control a game character. Game (icy tower?) was using directx input system (I think?) and somehow it was ignoring keybd_event calls but this method worked. I do not know how close to hardware you need to be but did this the trick for me. I used virtual key codes but turned them into scancodes for this answer.

```c
UINT PressKeyScan(WORD scanCode)
{
    INPUT input[1] = {0};
    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[0].ki.wVk = NULL;
    input[0].ki.wScan = scanCode;
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;

    UINT ret = SendInput(1, input, sizeof(INPUT));

    return ret;
}

UINT ReleaseKeyScan(WORD scanCode)
{
    INPUT input[1] = {0};
    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[0].ki.wVk = NULL;
    input[0].ki.wScan = scanCode;
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;


    UINT ret = SendInput(1, input, sizeof(INPUT));

    return ret;
}
```

To simulate press and release you use them sequentially (or you may create a separate function for press and release that use same [INPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-input) structure).

```c
WORD scanCodeSpace = 0x39;
PressKeyScan(scanCodeSpace);
ReleaseKeyScan(scanCodeSpace)
```

You can use [MapVirtualKeyA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeya) to get scan code from virtual key code.

Answer (score 1):

`keybd_event()` is deprecated, use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.

`SendInput()` posts its simulated events to the same queue that the hardware driver posts its events to, as shown in the below diagram from Raymond Chen's blog:

[When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773)

[image]